# Time Machine requires huge amount of storage

Tags: backup, time-machine, nas

So I have a MBP 16' with 1TB SSD running Big Sur. Right now it has 731GB space available so a total of ~270GB used.

I setup a SMB for Time Machine backup on my Synology NAS. It has 1.4TB of free space on it. The backup failed complaining

"The backup disk needs 4.52 TB for the backup but only 1.42 TB are available. Select a larger backup disk or make the backup smaller by excluding files.".

Is it normal that I should have 16 times of data to do 1 backup?

Comment: Have you seen in TM preferences/Options the size of the save and may be add to the  exclude list some volumes or externals disk?

Comment: @Jean_JD I don't have any external disks connected. I did exclude bunch of folders (Dropbox, iCloud, Virtual Machines, github repo, etc.)